# Java pass open socket to class?

Tags: java, networking

I have a simple server program here, and I am trying to design something to handle packets received.

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Listener implements Runnable {
    ServerSocket listenerSocket;
    Socket connection = null;
    OutputStream out;
    InputStream in;
    String packet;
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try{
            listenerSocket = new ServerSocket(7331); //General socket setup
            System.out.println("Waiting for connection");
            connection = listenerSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Connection received from " + connection.getInetAddress());
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream()); 
            do{
                try{
                    packet = (String)in.readLine(); // Get packet data
                    System.out.println("Data:" + packet);
                    Thread handler = new Thread(new Handler(packet)); // Handler class will take / parse packet data.
                    handler.start(); 
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }while(!packet.equals("shutdown"));
        }
        catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            try{
                in.close();
                out.close();
                listenerSocket.close();
            }
            catch(IOException ioException){
                ioException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am using a separate Handler thread to handle each packet, as you can see. What I want to do though is send "updates" to the client as the handler completes its processes. For example, the handler finishes copying a file, sends data back to the client to tell it that, and then it starts to copy another file, and lets the client know that. Obviously, the handler thread cant access the socket though. Any suggestions or improvements I can make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

1. Pass the socket to the `Handler` in the constructor; make sure you synchronize access to the socket.
2. Set up a response queue into which `Handler` instances put the response data; create another thread with the responsibility of taking responses off the queue and sending them back on the socket.

Comment: `make sure you synchronize access to the socket.` How would I go about doing this. Can I still pass it even though its open?

Comment: You could do that also